# How to load data using dynamic ng-include with AngularJS with correct controller for each page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I realize that this isn't an entirely new question, but after days of trying to get this to work I seem to not understand something fundamentally, despite the extensive searches I have done as I cannot get my app to work.

I have a web app with a side `nav` and a main `div` in the center. I am using `ng-include` to populate the main `div` based on the side `nav` that is clicked. Originally I was using `ng-show`, but because there is so much data on each page I don't want to load all of the side `nav` options. I then switched to using `ng-include` which works great. However, I am now having issues with two way binding and loading an `init()` function when a side `nav` is clicked. I am trying to keep this simple as this is my first app using AngularJS, and I must use AngularJS since some of the pages being viewed are already existing with their own controllers and pages fully functioning. Because many pages are already operational, I simply want to display the HTML from an existing page that works and link up the correct controller for that page. As a temporary solution, I have taken all of the code from the various controllers and stuck them in one controller. However, this creates other problems which will require me to change a lot of code, so I would much rather have each page with its own controller.

Therefore, what is the correct way to use `ng-include` in a way that will allow me to load the HTML page, link it to the proper controller and then run some kind of `init()` with all of the `ng-model` pieces still working?

It is likely that I am doing more than one thing wrong. My actual app has a lot of data and is quite big. Therefore, I have extracted very small parts of it and typed up the following example to show what I am trying to accomplish and the latest thing I have tried.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PL Releasing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body  ng-app="indexApp" ng-controller="indexController" style="width: 100%">
        <div>
            <div>               
                <a ng-click="showpage('page1')">PAGE1</a>
                <a ng-click="showpage('page2')">PAGE2</a>               
            </div>
            <div ng-include="templateURL">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('indexApp', []);

app.controller('indexController', function($scope) {

    //index.html
    $scope.showpage = function(pageName) {

        switch(pageName) {
            case "page1":
                $scope.templateURL = '/assets/pages/page1.html';                
                break
            case "page2":
                $scope.templateURL = '/assets/pages/page2.html';                
                break
            default:
                $scope.templateURL = ''
                console.log(pageName)   
        }       
    }   
})

app.controller('page1Controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.ListData = []

    $scope.populatePage1 = function() {
        $("#data").html('loaded 1')
        $scope.getPage1Data()
        //POPULATE <select> AND OTHER STATIC DATA
    }

    $scope.page1Init = function() {
        $scope.populatePage1()
        //RUN OTHER INIT FUNCTIONS HERE
    }

    $scope.getPage1Data = function() {
        $http.get("http://127.0.01:9090/getListData?queryName=page1Data")
            .then (function(resp) {
                $scope.ListData = resp.data;            
            });
    }

})

app.controller('page2Controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.populatePage1 = function() {
        $("#data").html('loaded 2')
        $scope.getPage1Data()
    }

    $scope.page1Init = function() {
        $scope.populatePage2()
        //RUN OTHER INIT FUNCTIONS HERE
    }

    $scope.getPage2Data = function() {
        $http.get("http://127.0.01:9090/getListData?queryName=page2Data")
            .then (function(resp) {
                $scope.ListData = resp.data;            
            });
    }

})
```

**page1.html**

```
<div ng-controller="page1.html" onload="page1init()">
    <p>THIS IS PAGE 1</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="page1Input" placeholder="Enter data"/>
    <br>
    <div>{{page1Input}}</div>
    <br>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <select style="width: 100px;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option ng-repeat="pjt in ListData" value="{{pjt.id}}">{{pjt.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the link to the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3b68HW?p=preview) I created trying to use ng-route.

Comment: Why can't you try using routing? [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)?

Comment: It isn't that I "can't", it's that I was not successful in doing so. I can post the code that I tried which I wasn't able to get working using that method and maybe you can point out my error. Would it be correct to add that code to the original question as an EDIT?

Comment: You can try setting up a fiddle and adding it to your original question or ask a different one. Editing the post in a radical way doesn't seem to be good since you already have an answer here posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AngularJS ngRoute:

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController'
  })

  //otherwise redirect to home
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/home"
  });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!!!!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Contact us!.';
});
```

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/oDFG8nTWVfvZj3cz33c6?p=preview) a sample demo in plnkr.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I was not able to get this to work in the Plunker I have added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You show use routing library like ngRoute .